# Conditionally style text in Angular2

Tags: angular, styles

I have a list of object like this {name : 'Susan', number : 1}. I need to show the name colored depending on the number (if the number is 1 the name has to be red, if 2 blue, if 3 green and if 4 orange).
In the template I have:

```
  <p *ngFor="let item of data">
    {{item.name}}
  </p>
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**NgClass**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

In **component**, create an object like this:

```
this.colorMap = {
  1: 'my-red',
  2: 'my-blue',
  3: 'my-green',
  4: 'my-orange'
};
```

And in **template**:

```
<p [ngClass]="colorMap[item.number]" *ngFor="let item of data">
  {{item.name}}
</p>
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Txbyq2s4DGBQgXORZRN?p=info)

Comment: Thank you, the most simple and effective answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `class` property binding

```
<p *ngFor="let item of data">
    <span [class.blue]="item.number === 1" [class.red]="item.number === 2" [class.green]="item.number === 3"> {{item.name}} </span> 
  </p>
```

Alternatively you can use the `[style.color]` property binding

```
<p *ngFor="let item of data">
    <span [style.color]="getColor(item.number)">{{item.name}}</span>
</p>

getColor(number){
    if(number ===1 ){
        return 'blue';
        }else if(number ===2 ) 
         {
            return 'red';
         } else if(number ===3 ) 
           {
                return 'green';
           }else {
            return '';
            }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Use NgClass:

myComponent.html

```
<p [ngClass]="getColor(item.number)" *ngFor="let item of data">
   {{item.name}}
 </p>
```

myComponent.ts

```
 @component({
    ...
    templateUrl: './myComponent.html',
    styles: [`
        .red: { background-color: 'red'; }
        .green: { background-color: 'green'; }
        .blue: { background-color: 'blue'; }
        .orange: { background-color: 'orange'; }
    `]
)
export class MyComponent {

  getColor(n:number) {
     return {
        'red': n === 1,
        'green': n === 2,
        'blue': n === 3,
        'orange': n === 4
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works, but this is not the correct way to do. By using a method to get the class from the HTML, Angular will be evaluating the result of getColor over and over in each digestion cycle. This will work just fine with the given example, but will cause performance issues with larger projects.

Comment: @adripanico ok nice explanation but can you explain the right way to do it?

Comment: There are some valid answers, basically you need to store the colors, instead of calculate the correct one in each case.

For example, you can attach the corresponding color to each item when you define them (or retrieve them from a request):

`data.forEach((item, index, array) => { item.color = getColor(index); });`

and then just use it in your markup:

`<p [ngClass]="item.color" *ngFor="let item of data"></p>`